# How to use selectInput in shiny for creating interactive result?

Tags: r, shiny

I am having the following simple code for creating the shiny interface to display the interactive volcano plot along with the result,

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("usevars", "Override x1, x2, and p"),
      numericInput("x1", "x1", value = 0),
      numericInput("x2", "x2", value = 0),
      numericInput("p", "p", value = 0),
      actionButton("btn", "Plot!")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotly::plotlyOutput("plt"),
      h2("Result"),
      tableOutput("result"),
      h2("Up-Regulated"),
      tableOutput("upreg"),
      h2("Down-Regulated"),
      tableOutput("downreg"),
      h2("Significant"),
      tableOutput("signif"),
      h2("Non-significant"),
      tableOutput("nonsignif")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  results <- reactive({
    req(input$btn)
    if (isolate(input$usevars)) {
      x1 <- isolate(input$x1)
      x2 <- isolate(input$x2)
      p <- isolate(input$p)
      volcanoplot_DE_fn(top_table, x1=x1, x2=x2, p=p)
    } else {
      list("Volcano Plot" = volcanoplot_DE_fn(top_table))
    }
  })
  output$plt <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    req(results())
    results()[["Volcano Plot"]]
  })
  output$result <- renderTable({
    res <- req(results())
    validate(
      need(isTRUE(isolate(input$usevars)), "'Results' not applicable without x1, x2, and p values")
    )
    res[["Results"]]
  })
  output$upreg <- renderTable({
    res <- req(results())
    validate(
      need(isTRUE(isolate(input$usevars)), "'Up-Regulated' not applicable without x1, x2, and p values")
    )
    res[["Up-Regulated"]]
  })
  output$downreg <- renderTable({
    res <- req(results())
    validate(
      need(isolate(input$usevars), "'Down-Regulated' not applicable without x1, x2, and p values")
    )
    res[["Down-Regulated"]]
  })
  output$signif <- renderTable({
    res <- req(results())
    validate(
      need(isolate(input$usevars), "'Significant' not applicable without x1, x2, and p values")
    )
    res[["Significant"]]
  })
  output$nonsignif <- renderTable({
    res <- req(results())
    validate(
      need(isolate(input$usevars), "'Non-significant' not applicable without x1, x2, and p values")
    )
    res[["Non-significant"]]
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The R function for creating the volcano plot is,

```
 volcanoplot_DE_fn <- function(top_table, x1 = NULL, x2 = NULL, p = NULL){
  
  logFC <- adj.P.Val <- diffexpressed <- NULL
  
  if(is.null(x1) && is.null(x2) && is.null(p)){
    logFC <- adj.P.Val <- NULL
    plot1 <- plotly::ggplotly(ggplot2::ggplot (top_table, ggplot2::aes(x = logFC, y = -log10(adj.P.Val)))+
                                ggplot2::geom_point())
    return(plot1)
  }
  
  else{
    #Changing the first column as a row name
    res_table <- top_table
    
    #Add a new variable for three level factors - Up, Down and NO
    
    res_table$diffexpressed <- "Non-significant"
    
    res_table$diffexpressed[res_table$logFC >=x2 & res_table$adj.P.Val < p] <- "Up"
    
    res_table$diffexpressed[res_table$logFC <=x1 & res_table$adj.P.Val < p] <- "Down"
    
    res_table$diffexpressed[res_table$logFC>x1 & res_table$logFC<x2 & res_table$adj.P.Val < p] <- "Significant"
    
    res_table$diffexpressed[res_table$logFC<x1 & res_table$logFC>x2 & res_table$adj.P.Val >p] <- "Non-signficant"
    
    #Create the plot
    plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = res_table, ggplot2::aes(x=logFC, y=-log10(adj.P.Val),
                                                           col = diffexpressed)) +
      ggplot2::geom_point()+
      ggplot2::theme_minimal()+
      ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=c("green","black","blue","red"))+
      ggplot2::geom_vline(xintercept = c(x1,x2), col = "azure4", size = 1) +
      ggplot2::geom_hline(yintercept = -log10(0.05), col = "darkgoldenrod4", lty = 11, size = 1)+
      ggplot2::ggtitle("Volcano Plot")+
      ggplot2::theme(plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    
    #Up-regulated proteins
    Up_protein <- subset(res_table, diffexpressed == "Up")
    
    #Down-regulated proteins
    Down_protein <- subset (res_table, diffexpressed == "Down")
    
    #Significant proteins
    Significant_protein <- subset (res_table, diffexpressed == "Significant")
    
    #Non-significant proteins
    Nonsignificant_protein <- subset (res_table, diffexpressed == "Non-significant")
    
    result = list ("Result" = res_table, "Volcano Plot" = plotly::ggplotly(plot),
                   "Up-regulated" = Up_protein, "Down-regulated" = Down_protein,
                   "Significant" = Significant_protein, "Non-significant" = Nonsignificant_protein)
    return(result)
  }
}
```

And the example input file (argument `top_table`) is,

```
structure(list(logFC = c(-0.926829032043393, 0.681144540789003, 
-1.18649156278779, -1.43134804156653, -0.50884223216455, -0.850207297894457, 
-0.40397810491605, -0.375723841695923, 0.478401914066644, -0.388074789824714, 
-0.490995476586484, -0.564804523712919, -0.329511849641868, -0.334536226244509, 
-0.3561146157165, 0.302143323392553, -0.422061744132034, -0.337510247397532, 
-0.660250810302653, -0.289685082008223, 0.644293500906045, -0.623417359513766, 
-0.274865849446631, -0.445733336632038, -0.41817770465466, -0.602879089548679, 
-0.223611536254431, -0.349641499898542, -0.334752861619826, -0.30885175114032, 
0.353570657705887, 0.293418077503585, -0.207750588102734, -0.310218040957469, 
-0.206595870936628, -0.293242455235159, -0.251804538942991, -0.223236615258688, 
-0.253084249515684, -0.309276188221322, -0.332305641660302, -0.192896523841583, 
0.2202161126093, -2.01794654635471, 0.210750903395478, -0.167245617935855, 
0.131929175463938, -0.127944380002418, -0.12745943419737, -0.121744771107814
), AveExpr = c(21.9868872786025, 24.628796260062, 21.7812197994545, 
25.4837480078087, 21.8468895744326, 23.9185532604068, 28.3892868838662, 
27.2661765890669, 22.4977562340893, 27.7945437030284, 25.0333305934335, 
27.4964139610481, 26.2317215313941, 22.3965745752166, 28.0861080786281, 
24.5257444169956, 25.7514775910115, 27.8543361702698, 25.3223101525423, 
27.6225487414349, 21.9169536725419, 22.1186939730091, 26.7684891499013, 
27.3153474291583, 25.3147892843167, 20.9155776004651, 29.2114613166524, 
27.6995565064235, 22.6012509514535, 24.5050017808205, 22.8416228606554, 
25.7116398840889, 28.9410046820178, 23.1159376081156, 26.0119073675606, 
28.7451811442493, 24.1664949096224, 27.8968819005476, 26.5807153401113, 
25.5047160436979, 26.1486370294939, 29.8283454104072, 23.0907906260256, 
22.3532889322841, 22.2093006872706, 25.009617220235, 28.7658744406554, 
28.5833120213652, 26.8451160973292, 28.8651226940472), t = c(-4.94593058607945, 
4.65062388375169, -4.49142257621527, -4.4913085155081, -4.38218257332631, 
-4.32097729555783, -4.24132625127728, -4.22192061832073, 4.21887472008688, 
-4.20813139151696, -4.1866515586108, -4.10068425225877, -4.05180294312135, 
-4.04099311974424, -4.02708785248981, 3.96259530608623, -3.89363528920799, 
-3.87255819112771, -3.79284233864152, -3.7067415424435, 3.67406662928203, 
-3.64345932318903, -3.63806717176531, -3.57872841156052, -3.53279411847166, 
-3.50824535702493, -3.43382992722864, -3.41125900648815, -3.39238420439011, 
-3.31356401265437, 3.20567656789838, 3.1546951092708, -3.06700502923069, 
-3.06031683869388, -2.96368311631921, -2.89231293384596, -2.86196102031527, 
-2.76001139289039, -2.72010351356265, -2.67266319430844, -2.65645652757708, 
-2.60842301937499, 2.48645868022969, -2.45435150027135, 2.37660887173995, 
-2.25345037417702, 2.10280705886313, -1.9033469841064, -1.53742605571369, 
-1.50249612667744), P.Value = c(0.00196093944322159, 0.00271747517080813, 
0.00325690169807963, 0.00325732855798045, 0.00369569556838783, 
0.00396995930137373, 0.00436122729247392, 0.00446289788590221, 
0.00447909284317941, 0.00453673592631098, 0.00465446139221242, 
0.00516059978260805, 0.00547529276134138, 0.00554770750848481, 
0.00564241567079105, 0.00610559446763967, 0.00664764446817117, 
0.00682371361038685, 0.00753744667796711, 0.00840153793725549, 
0.00875737231428858, 0.00910568074764738, 0.00916859705837347, 
0.00989321528689002, 0.010497046165467, 0.0108361238780444, 0.0119389043915242, 
0.0122970540660915, 0.0126055133074444, 0.0139873316716138, 0.0161508709912167, 
0.0172965169900362, 0.0194766054749851, 0.0196545822392388, 0.0224298798997557, 
0.0247471243750903, 0.0258086511684442, 0.0297425235866536, 0.0314509742494649, 
0.0336174308976243, 0.0343930642631356, 0.0368042341454153, 0.0437552773414213, 
0.045803498688398, 0.0511848237747967, 0.0610790150585509, 0.075880780857114, 
0.101166203220985, 0.170553022075428, 0.179132945504504), adj.P.Val = c(0.0188080522359702, 
0.0188080522359702, 0.0188080522359702, 0.0188080522359702, 0.0188080522359702, 
0.0188080522359702, 0.0188080522359702, 0.0188080522359702, 0.0188080522359702, 
0.0188080522359702, 0.0188080522359702, 0.0188080522359702, 0.0188080522359702, 
0.0188080522359702, 0.0188080522359702, 0.0189547600288524, 0.0189547600288524, 
0.0189547600288524, 0.0198353859946503, 0.0199317327355945, 0.0199317327355945, 
0.0199317327355945, 0.0199317327355945, 0.0206108651810209, 0.02083869976547, 
0.02083869976547, 0.0217336436335249, 0.0217336436335249, 0.0217336436335249, 
0.0233122194526897, 0.0260497919213172, 0.0270258077969315, 0.0289037974106453, 
0.0289037974106453, 0.0320426855710796, 0.0343710060765143, 0.0348765556330326, 
0.0391348994561232, 0.0403217618582883, 0.0419427612965068, 0.0419427612965068, 
0.0438145644588277, 0.050878229466769, 0.052049430327725, 0.0568720264164408, 
0.0663902337592945, 0.0807242349543766, 0.105381461688526, 0.174033695995335, 
0.179132945504504), B = c(-0.850492449919733, -1.16687535012417, 
-1.34359268150789, -1.34372084949529, -1.46736843362162, -1.53761530370444, 
-1.62999813966432, -1.6526709218099, -1.65623550463376, -1.66882103119162, 
-1.6940435032919, -1.79578127715274, -1.85419297435006, -1.86716534441987, 
-1.88388162639586, -1.96184024513877, -2.04597521509856, -2.0718494487634, 
-2.17037634495941, -2.27796853395671, -2.31911413113806, -2.357811391446, 
-2.36464423726666, -2.44014078565088, -2.49896067049816, -2.53052919944819, 
-2.62678129336886, -2.65613851031067, -2.6807456032167, -2.78405670294593, 
-2.9268607360489, -2.99487486407223, -3.11261366389149, -3.12163109096479, 
-3.25247304934597, -3.34972936938279, -3.39123590316825, -3.53122071360018, 
-3.58622883013911, -3.65175114056107, -3.67416442667552, -3.74066979776697, 
-3.90991503829754, -3.95452135738893, -4.06253811155549, -4.23342260175805, 
-4.44132539935597, -4.71280059107858, -5.18921306189543, -5.2325444706471
)), row.names = c("P30657", "P32598", "P38116", "P40893", "Q12044", 
"P38912", "P36008", "P50861", "P32623", "P0CX51.P0CX52", "A6ZM02.B3LLJ2.B5VP69.C7GVZ9.P23248", 
"P14126", "P33416", "Q04013", "P04802", "Q02821", "Q04947", "P16862", 
"Q00055", "P52910", "P47039", "P21734", "P34227", "P32316", "P38999", 
"P21304", "P19414", "P06106", "P46990", "P53303", "Q02805", "P32861", 
"P17505", "P40472.P53616", "Q12074", "A7A0V3.B3LT19.P46654.A6ZUM5.B3LI22.P32905", 
"Q07799", "P02400", "P23542", "P38221", "P53691", "P19882", "P52553", 
"P12945", "Q01662", "P23180", "P04806", "P10592", "Q12335", "P00817"
), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to add `selectInput` option in `sidebarPanel` with 10 different datasets like above.

And I have to modify the above shiny page which will give interactive plot and results based on the data type chosen from the `selectInput`.

So how I can I modify the `server` code for this purpose.

In `ui` code I can add the follwing code for selecting any one dataset out of ten datasets,

```
selectInput("combination", "Choose data", 
                                         c("knn_vsn_data", "knn_loess_data", "knn_rlr_data",
                                           "lls_vsn_data", "lls_loess_data", "lls_rlr_data",
                                           "svd_vsn_data", "svd_loess_data", "svd_rlr_data", "Original data")),
```

So kindly suggest me how to change `server` code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test, but this theoretically works to change the dataset. I added caching for you. No guarantee that this works.

```
output$example <- renderPlot(
    input$combination %>%
        ggplot(aes(
            x = logFC, y = -log10(adj.P.Val),
            col = diffexpressed
        )) +
        geom_point() +
        theme_minimal() +
        scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "black", "blue", "red")) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = c(x1, x2), col = "azure4", size = 1) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = -log10(0.05), col = "darkgoldenrod4", lty = 11, size = 1) +
        ggtitle("Volcano Plot") +
        theme(plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(hjust = 0.5)) %>% 
        bindCache(input$combination)
)
```

I think this should work if you have a selectInput() for the x, y, and column (idk about the col).

```
output$example <- renderPlot(
    input$combination %>%
        ggplot(aes_string(
            x = input$x_choice, y = input$y_choice,
            col = input$col_choice
        )) +
        geom_point() +
        theme_minimal() +
        scale_color_manual(values = c("green", "black", "blue", "red")) +
        geom_vline(xintercept = c(x1, x2), col = "azure4", size = 1) +
        geom_hline(yintercept = -log10(0.05), col = "darkgoldenrod4", lty = 11, size = 1) +
        ggtitle("Volcano Plot") +
        theme(plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(hjust = 0.5)) %>% 
        bindCache(input$combination, input$x_choice, input$y_choice, input$col_choice)
)
```

Comment: The functions for the plot I have already mentioned. So can you give `server` code, which will give results and plot based on `selectInput` option without changing the R function.

Comment: you have `plot <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = res_table`. That means in your server.R, that plot is hardcoded to data=res_table. I have `data = input$combination`. Put that in your server.R.


Note: you will have to put your `plot <- ` in your server.R. Getting the plot from `source(plot.R)` won't work. Also, take a look at this: https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/pipe-r-tutorial (ctrl shift m)